# Custom URL Rewrite If a condition is met

Tags: php, magento-1, url, url-rewrite

I'm looking for a way to change URLs if a condition is met. Something like:

URL: `http://mysiteurl/`

```
$url = 'http://mysiteurl/';

if ($userGroup == 'ABC') { 
    $url .= 'user/ABC/';
}
```

The new URL will be:  `http://mysiteurl/user/ABC/`

**But the page accessed will be the same.**

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I didn't implement your solution yet, this task is paused, but I created a alternative way without change magento URL structure using window.history.pushState(null, null 'http://mysiteurl/userABC/'); in javascript to create a fake URL. And redirecting at index.php with header('Location: http://mysiteurl/');

Comment: I still intend to implement your solution and check if it best suits my question. If it's true I will give you the check mark ✔.

Comment: I agree, I will add my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a logic then you implement it in an observer.

```
$url = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->getRequestPath(); //www.domaine.com/index.php/
$CustomerGroup = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); //02 for exemple
echo Mage::getUrl($url, array('user' => $CustomerGroup));  
//www.domaine.com/index.php/user/02/
```

Comment: Ok, understood! But why I should do an observer for this? and what event should I observ?

Comment: an observer to do it for all pages, else you have to do it in each page and is not a best practice, the event i don't know try this one `controller_front_init_routers` but im not sure

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but to do a generic implementation without change magento URL structure I add this on `index.php` to make a redirect to `http://mysiteurl/` if the user go to `http://mysiteurl/user/ABC/`

```
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$get = '';
$first = true;

// create get string
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get .= $first ? '?' : '&';
    $get .= $key . '=' . $value;
    $first = false;
}

// remove get from url
$url = str_replace($get, '', $url);

preg_match("/user.*/", $url, $pregMatchUser);

if($pregMatchUser) {
    $url = preg_replace("/user.*/", '', $url);

    // add get to url
    $url .= $get;

    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit();
}
```

And then create a fake URL with JavaScript, using `window.history.replaceState`:

```
var url = window.location.toString();
var userGroupUrl = 'user/' + App.userGroup + '/';
var newUrl, index = url.indexOf("?");
if(index == -1) {
    newUrl = url[url.length - 1] == '/' ? url + userGroupUrl : url + '/' + userGroupUrl;
} else {
    newUrl = url.replace('?', userGroupUrl + '?');
}

window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, newUrl);
```

**Of course, if you do this you will not be able to use `/user/` in your URL for another thing.**